# How can I make the CLONE STAMP tool act the same when in bitmap mode compared to grayscale?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, creative-cloud, bitmap

When I use the clone stamp tool, I get my selection and then I proceed to hover my brush over the image and get a little preview of what it's going to look like if I decide to press down.

This only happens when the image is set to **grayscale** mode. Is there a way to make this happen when the image is set to **bitmap**?

here is a screenshot of the grayscale image
[image]

and here is the bitmap one
[image]

You can see the outline of my circular clone stamp and the preview that it shows only in grayscale.

Comment: Please include any screen shots *in* your post, not linked to a site - web filters on our proxy servers/firewalls prevent some of us from seeing images external to SE.